# Getting a list of waypoints assuming that there is a map

Tags: java, beginner, android, serialization

I'm a beginner learning ROS. I'm developing an android application that will control my robot and that includes getting the list of waypoints to display it to my spinner. How do you get the list of waypoints to my topic /waypoints assuming that there is a map?

I've already done the code for subscribing to the topic /waypoints and serializing its msg type

This is my code for serializing the msg-type of the topic /waypoints:

```
public class WaypointList {

    @SerializedName("header")
    @Expose
    public Header header;
    @SerializedName("pose")
    @Expose
    public Pose pose;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("secs")
    @Expose
    public int secs;
    @SerializedName("nsecs")
    @Expose
    public int nsecs;
    @SerializedName("position")
    @Expose
    public Position position;
    @SerializedName("orientation")
    @Expose
    public Orientation orientation;
    @SerializedName("y")
    @Expose
    public float y;
    @SerializedName("x")
    @Expose
    public float x;
    @SerializedName("z")
    @Expose
    public float z;
    @SerializedName("w")
    @Expose
    public float w;
    @SerializedName("stamp")
    @Expose
    public Stamp stamp;
    @SerializedName("frame_id")
    @Expose
    public String frameId;
    @SerializedName("seq")
    @Expose
    public int seq;
    @SerializedName("waypoints")
    @Expose
    public List<WaypointList> waypoints = null;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public WaypointList() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param waypoints
     */
    public WaypointList(List<WaypointList> waypoints, Stamp stamp, String frameId, int seq, float y, float x, float z, float w, Position position, Orientation orientation, int secs, int nsecs, Header header, Pose pose, String name) {
        super();
        this.header = header;
        this.pose = pose;
        this.name = name;
        this.secs = secs;
        this.nsecs = nsecs;
        this.position = position;
        this.orientation = orientation;
        this.y = y;
        this.x = x;
        this.z = z;
        this.w = w;
        this.stamp = stamp;
        this.frameId = frameId;
        this.seq = seq;
        this.waypoints = waypoints;
    }
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're looking for and likely that this is in the wrong subsection of stackexchange. At the moment you have a class which contains a list of your class and nothing more. With nothing else to actually review in your code, I would recommend `public class WaypointList extends List`. Improvements can be what exactly you want your robot to do with the waypoints -- for instance nearest neighbor (and if that's the case, this is definitely in the wrong location).

Comment: @DavidFisher apologies. I've edited my codes regarding my question. basically i want my robot to go from point a to point b from the listed waypoints in my topic (/waypoints). i needed a variable that will hold all the data to be able to display it to my spinner.